# Does change variable of a function will change the upper bound of the integral of the function?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

If I was told $g$ is bounded and satisfies
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}|g(x)|dx\leq C \leq \infty
$$
Can I say that for every $y\in\mathbb{R}$,
$$
\int_\mathbb{R}|g(y-x)|dx\leq C \leq \infty 
$$
I intuitively suggest it is correct but can anyone convince me with reasons such that this is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know how to do a change of variable in an integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple argument is that the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(x-c)$ is that $f(x-c)$ is just $f(x)$ shifted horizontally. Hence, the integral over all of $\Bbb R$ must be the same. ($f(c-x)$ is just $f$ shifted and then flipped horizontally.)

You can also argue with a $u$-substitution, $u := y-x \implies du = -dx$, giving

$$\int_{\Bbb R} |g(y-x)| \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(y-x)| \, dx = \int_{\infty}^{-\infty} |g(u)| \, (-du) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty |g(u)| \, du$$